# (Discord.js) Bot only playing music when hosted locally, otherwise joins and leaves immediately

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I built a bot with Discord.js and it's running on a few friends' servers but I've had a persistent problem that I can't solve and I can't think of anything else to try. When I host the bot on any hosting service, the !play command results in the bot joining the voice channel, returning the "now playing" embed as usual, leaving immediately, and saying that the queue is empty. I know people ran into issues while hosting on Heroku and Glitch so in addition to those I've tried both Digital Ocean and AWS and had the same result every time. When hosted locally, either with 'yarn start' or a hosting service's local version CLI command like 'heroku local', everything works perfectly. This would indicate to me that the code works fine for all music commands (hence why I haven't included any snippets here), there's just something that I'm missing when the bot is hosted.

There are a variety of other commands including current weather/forecasts, ASCII text formatting, and chat moderation features that work just fine when hosted as well. The Youtube search command works so it doesn't seem like there's an issue with the bot's ability to access the Youtube API (I'm using ytdl-core for playback) in general, it seems limited to this playback issue. I've spent a ton of time trying to figure this out and consulted every relevant resource I could find and nothing seems to work. I've installed every ffmpeg- or opus-related buildpack people have used to solve issues so I have no idea what I'm missing at this point. Anyone else ever encounter similar issues?

Comment: Are there any environment variables the bot is using that aren't set for the other hosts? Some debugging results would also be helpful.

Comment: For me, running on Heroku does not have this issue.

Comment: @slothiful The environment variables are the same across all platforms and there seem to be no issues with access. I've tried to debug but the issue isn't a bug per se -- rather than play the current queue item, it simply skips to the portion of the code that says the queue is empty and then leaves the voice channel. This is all working properly so it doesn't return any error messages.

Comment: Log the queue and any relevant variables each step of the code to find out what exactly is happening from a back-end perspective. That should help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @slothiful Going through it now and I'll see if I come up with anything.